# running an oracle sql command without waiting for result

Tags: oracle, delphi, sql-insert

I have an oracle database which I am accessing using delphi with an ODAC component.
I would like to populate a table using a select statement and don't want to wait for the sql to complete before moving on to next delphi command.
I have tried using TOraSQL with non-blocking set to true but although the program moves on without any delay the sql doesn't populate the table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any Delphi-related ideas (as I don't know it), but - as far as Oracle is concerned - you could

- put that code into a stored procedure
- schedule a job (using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` or older (but simpler) `DBMS_JOB`) to run *right now* from Delphi
- job (i.e. the procedure) would run in the background, while ...
- ... your Delphi code would go on